# Convert simple Java application to Dynamic web project

Tags: java, websphere

I'm trying to convert a simple project to a dynamic web project.

I am using WebSphere Application Server, where I want to run my simple application.

When I right click and run as a Java application, it runs smoothly. Where do I make changes so that I could be able to run this on WebSphere Application Server?

**SampleProject**

```
--src
|  |--main
|  |   |--java
|  |     --com
|  |       --mykong
|  |         --core
|  |            --App.java
|  |            --HelloWorld.java       
|  |
|  |   |--resouces
|  |      --SpringBeans.xml
|  |
|  |--test
|     |--java
|         --com
|          --mykong
|             --core
|               --AppTest.java
|
|--target
|--.classpath
|--.project
|--.pom.xml
```

**App.java**

```
package com.mkyong.core;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "SpringBeans.xml");

        HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloBean");
        obj.printHello();
    }
}
```

**HelloWorld.java**

```
package com.mkyong.core;

/**
 * Spring bean
 * 
 */
public class HelloWorld {
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void printHello() {
        System.out.println("Spring 3 : Hello ! " + name);
    }
}
```

**SpringBeans.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="helloBean" class="com.mkyong.core.HelloWorld">
        <property name="name" value="Mkyong" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**AppTest.java**

```
package com.mkyong.core;

import junit.framework.Test;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import junit.framework.TestSuite;

/**
 * Unit test for simple App.
 */
public class AppTest 
    extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * Create the test case
     *
     * @param testName name of the test case
     */
    public AppTest( String testName )
    {
        super( testName );
    }

    /**
     * @return the suite of tests being tested
     */
    public static Test suite()
    {
        return new TestSuite( AppTest.class );
    }

    /**
     * Rigourous Test :-)
     */
    public void testApp()
    {
        assertTrue( true );
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the m2e plugin or the maven-eclipse-plugin to create the Eclipse project?

Comment: I am not using any plugin, I downloaded this sample from mykong website.

Comment: i have manually added dependency jars in classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using Maven the easiest is probably to configure [wtpversion](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html#wtpversion) in the [maven-eclipse-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/). And run the following on the project:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

The other option would be to install the [Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/maven-integration-eclipse-wtp).